# How to use a linked exe file that comes with a Nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, phantomjs, nuget

Having installed Phantomjs via Nuget, there is an executable deep in the packages folder. The package also places a link/placeholder in the project root `phantomjs.exe`. The file does not appear in the filesystem, only in Visual Studio. It has a property "Full Path" that points to the physical file.

How can I execute that file from my code? The following code causes a `The system cannot find the file specified`.

```
var p = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    FileName = @"~/phantomjs.exe"
};
p.StartInfo = startInfo;

p.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the real file extension, it surely is .lnk in which case it won't work with things like CreateProcess, which your used API surely is a wrapper around. If it's not an lnk file, check if it's a hard- or symbolic link and if the target exists. "dir" on the shell should show you. If it's a lnk file you can try to use ShellExecute, because it seems your API already provides a flag for that, or maybe even replace the lnk file with a custom created hard- or symbolic link or need to use cmd.exe, which should be able to execute lnk files like it opens doc file paths.

Comment: The file does not appear in the filesystem, only in VS. It has a property "Full Path" that I need to use in that case.

Comment: And the full path points to the real file deep in your structure? In that case you will need to do some VS related "things", because neither ShellExecute nor CreateProcess will know about this special VS link. You simply can't just pass it to a wrapper of the Win32 API, you need to rersolve it first somehow or make sure that your used API does it for you, which already doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then why would the creator of the package even bother placing such a link if it's unusable? Grrmmpf. With every new version this path will change, so hardcoding it is painful.

Comment: It is not unusable to VS, only to Win32 and wrappers around that. VS does surely resolve those paths on it's own with some kind of logic. If you can access that, I didn't found anything, but I'm no VS pro, you can resolve the path on your own and pass it to your API. Else you simply can't use it and need another solution for whatever your problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that there is another copy of the file in the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

The Nuget package actually installs another copy of the executable in the `bin` folder, which is usable in a convenient way.

The path can be mapped via

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/")
```

in WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of `phantomjs.exe` - it should be copied to output directory ("copy if newer" or "copy always"). If it's not - set it. This way the executable is copied to the output directory on build, and then available to your process.

The problem with your code is the path. This works for me:

```
var p = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    FileName = @"phantomjs.exe"
};
p.StartInfo = startInfo;

p.Start();
```